# R markdown with chunks in both Python and R - is there possibility to use shared variables?

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, bookdown

I prepared following R markdown document that mixes both Python and R! code:

````
---
title: "Sample document"
abstract: "This is a sample abstract."
author: "Mateusz Kędzior"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    keep_tex: true
---

## Sample Text

I wish to show Python histogram (Fig. \@ref(fig:FirstHist)) in my .tex

```{python, echo=FALSE}
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = np.random.randn(50, 4)
plt.hist(w, facecolor='green')

# Now I wish to include histogram in the generated document, so I've tried:
# plt.show()
# Unfortunately it shows shortly a window with histogram and waits until I close it.
# I think there's no such possibility, so I save it to file and then inserts in R code chunk:
plt.savefig('FirstHist.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

```{r FirstHist, echo=FALSE, fig.align="center", out.width = ".8\\linewidth", fig.cap="Histogram of w"}
knitr::include_graphics("FirstHist.png")
```
````

that compiles to:

[image: compiled version of my R markdown code]

As you can see, I repeat *FirstHist* string 3 times in my code chunks.

I wonder if there's any possibility of refactoring - using one shared (between all chunks) variable?

Comment: Is it acceptable to write the variable to disk (as a simple text file)?

Comment: If it is the only option, yes.